# Selecting all files of certain extensions in specified directory and below with Glob & Node.js

Tags: node.js, glob

Why below glob does not select the files directly below `Pages/Open`?

```
/Pages/Open/**/*.pug
```

[image]

[Fiddle](https://globster.xyz/?q=%2FPages%2FOpen%2F**%2F*.pug&f=%2FPages%2FOpen%2FEntryPoint.pug%2C%2FPages%2FOpen%2F_Partial.pug%2C%2FPages%2FOpen%2FTop%2FEntryPoint.pug%2C%2FPages%2FOpen%2FTop%2F_Partial.pug%2C%2FPages%2FOpen%2FTop%2FSubDirectory1%2F_Partial.pug%2C%2FPages%2FOpen%2FTop%2FSubDirectory1%2FNotPartial.pug%2C%2FPages%2FOpen%2FTop%2F_SubDirectory2%2F_Partial.pug%2C%2FPages%2FOpen%2FTop%2F_SubDirectory2%2FNotPartial.pug)

Comment: `/Pages/**/*.pug` use this

Comment: @Abhishekchandel, Thank you for the comment. What if I need below `Open` directory only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const glob = require('glob')

glob("./Pages/Open/**/*.pug", (er, files) => {
  console.log({
    files: files
  })
  // outputs the following ...
  // {
  //   files: [
  //     './Pages/Open/_Partial.pug',
  //     './Pages/Open/EntryPoint.pug',
  //     './Pages/Open/Top/_Partial.pug',
  //     './Pages/Open/Top/_SubDirectory2/_Partial.pug',
  //     './Pages/Open/Top/_SubDirectory2/NotPartial.pug',
  //     './Pages/Open/Top/EntryPoint.pug',
  //     './Pages/Open/Top/SubDirectory1/_Partial.pug',
  //     './Pages/Open/Top/SubDirectory1/NotPartial.pug'
  //   ]
  // }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but please, answer my question - "Why below glob does not select the files directly below Pages/Open"?

Comment: `./Pages` is relative to working directory. `/Pages` is relative to root for filesystem.